# Do I need to use posts or pages in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, web, categories

I am working on a medical news website (WordPress) and I'm doubting for a while because I don't know if I need to create posts or pages to show information about health conditions. I've read a lot of articles about pages vs posts and I know that posts should be date-based and that pages should be static, but I'm doubting because it may happen that the conditions information needs to be updated by a doctor (rarely).

Anyone?

Comment: You should use posts to talk about a specific health condition, something like this

Page -> Health Conditions
    Posts -> Health Condition 1
              -> Health Condition 2

Comment: Use custom post types and custom taxonomies

Comment: Could you give me an example in what way I can use custom posts and taxonomies? Please read my comment below to see what content I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to use [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). With a custom post type, you can create a new 'section' (next to posts and pages). You can create a new post type for every type of content, like health condition information, blogs and special reports.

You can then set different permalinks for every post type, like yoursite.com/health-conditions/demo-condition and create seperate archive pages to show all posts from that post type.

Comment: Should I add custom post types for all content like news, health conditions information, blogs and special reports, or just for health conditions information? I don't understand when to uses post (including categories) and when to use custom post types. What do you think?

Comment: Posts are usually being used for news items and blogs, so I would use that one for news (maybe also blog, but that's depending on your site structure and your preferences). Pages are meant for static content pages, like an 'about us' or a 'contact' page. For all the other content types I recommend creating a custom post type, because the content type is different than posts (news, blogs) and pages. I think you need to use categories for separating posts of the same type, not for separating posts of different types.

Comment: Ok, so in summary (please let me know if I am right):
Blogs and news posts will stay normal posts. Health conditions information, medicines information and special reports will get new post types. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I should do it :) Good luck!

Comment: One more thing; Can I assign categories to posts with custom post type?

Comment: Yes, you can create custom taxonomies for that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies

Answer (score 0):

I created a lot of websites within the last few years and I would recommend that you use pages for your purpose!

Posts are more for people who do blogging and create new posts in a period of time. I do not know what exactly you want to do with your medical news site but I would prefer creating new pages for everything you want to create.

It is up to you and I am pretty sure that both (posts & pages) will work for your website :)

Comment: I will have different types of content on my website: news, health conditions information, blogs written by doctors, special reports. So far I have used categories to sort them but I was not sure about the conditions information because the time is not important and it will not contain a features image